# python, insertion sort, strings

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort this list without using built-in sort().
I figured I could use insertion sort, but I've never really used it before.
My code doesn't seem to be working. What is wrong with it?
Thank you.

```
fruits = ['grape', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'peach', 'cherry']



for i in range(1, len(fruits)):
    tmp = fruits[i]
    j = i-1;
    while (j>0 and fruits[j] > tmp):
        fruits[j+1] = fruits[j]
        j = j-1
        fruits[j+1] = tmp
print(fruits)
```

Comment: Are you actually calling `insertion_sort` anywhere? If you did, you'd get a NameError, as `lens` isn't defined.

Comment: Also - if you're just beginning - don't get into the habit of ending lines with `;` - they're not required...

Comment: I followed your suggestions. thanks! still trying to figure out what's wrong

Comment: So what is the output of fruits you're getting...?

Comment: I still get the original 'fruits' list. ['grape', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'peach', 'cherry']

Comment: @Lexi I get `['grape', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'peach', 'strawberry']` (so things are swapping about)... anyway... put some print statements in there... show what `fruits` is on entering and before leaving each loop and what the variables you're exchanging are... then just pen and paper wise work out if that's what you'd do... you'll very soon identify the problem...

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly too!

```
Fruits= ['grape', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'peach', 'cherry']
def insertionSortFruits():
    for i in range(1,len(Fruits)):
        key=Fruits[i]
        j=i-1
        while j>=0 and key<Fruits[j]:
            Fruits[j+1]=Fruits[j]
            j=j-1
        Fruits[j+1]=key
    print(Fruits)

#Testing
insertionSortFruits()
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed two things and it works. Not exactly meant as an answer but might help you forward.

```
fruits = ['grape', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'peach', 'cherry']

for i in range(0, len(fruits)):
    tmp = fruits[i]
    j = i-1;
    print(fruits)
    while (j>-1 and fruits[j] > tmp):
        fruits[j+1] = fruits[j] 
        j = j-1
        fruits[j+1] = tmp

print(fruits)
```

Could be made smaller this way:

```
fruits = ['grape', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'peach', 'cherry']

for i in range(len(fruits)):

    tmp = fruits[i]
    j = i-1 # stop index
    while (j > -1 and fruits[j] > tmp):
        fruits[j:j+2] = tmp,fruits[j] #swap places
        j -= 1

print(fruits)
```

Returns:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'grape', 'peach', 'strawberry']
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The swap operation which appears in the inner loop seems quite strange. If I were a betting person I'd say that's where the error occurs.

Try doing a clean "swap", like you'd do it for three variables:

```
a = 10
b = 20
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp
print(a) # prints 20
print(b) # prints 10
```

Your code will become something like:

```
for i in range(1, len(fruits)):
    j = i-1
    while j >= 0 and fruits[j] > fruits[j+1]:
        # Swap the two consecutive elements which are unsorted
        tmp = fruits[j]
        fruits[j] = fruits[j+1]
        fruits[j+1] = tmp
        # Prepare to process previous two consecutive elements
        j = j-1
```

Comment: It makes sense! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First replace lens() by len().

In other hand, you not apply your function over fruits array, you only declare function.

Finally, arrays start at index 0, so j must be> = 0.

Corrected code:

```
fruits = ['grape', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'peach', 'cherry']

def insertion_sort(fruits):

   for i in range(1, len(fruits)):
       tmp = fruits[i]
       j = i-1;
       while (j>=0 and fruits[j] > tmp):
           fruits[j+1] = fruits[j];
           j = j-1;
      fruits[j+1] = tmp;
   return fruits

if __name__ == "__main__":

     fruits2 = insertion_sort(fruits)
     print(fruits2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand the first part, but what does
if __name__ p == "__main__" part do??

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__" is for execute a .py how "main program"

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = ['grape', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'peach', 'cherry']
for i in range(1,len(fruits))
temp=fruits[i]
k = i
    while k > 0 and tmp < fruits[k - 1]:
        fruits[k] = fruits[k - 1]
        k -= 1
    fruits[k] = tmp
print fruits
```

your loop will execute one time less as 
   j=i-1
   j>0
it should be
   j>-1

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help!